# Ruby - Compare/target specific values in arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, compare, sequence

I want to compare two arrays that it only shows true if the arrays are in sequence with no other value in between or if it is backwards.

**Example array**

```
a = [1,3]
b = [[1],[1,3],[1,3,8],[4,1,3],[1,8,3],[3,1]]
```

**Expected result:**

```
[1]     #=> false
[1,3]   #=> true
[1,3,8] #=> true
[4,1,3] #=> true
[1,8,3] #=> false
[3,1]   #=> false
```

How can I target so that it will only show true if the results are in a sequence?

Comment: I assume you attempted the problem yourself first? If not then get into the habit of doing so. If you were unsure of how to approach the problem then you probably need to do another course or follow another book. Click the [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) tag for more info on resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b.map { |c| c.each_cons(a.size).include?(a) }
=> [false, true, true, true, false, false]
```